# Can't tie command to button Python 3.7

Tags: python, python-3.x, button, tkinter

I am trying to get a button to do some stuff in Python (using Tkinter). I want the button to get the current choice of a combobox and print it on screen.

The graphical layout is 3 separate frames, but both the button and the combobox reside in the same frame (frame #2).

**The problem is that i cannot refer to the combobox. The errors i am getting read:**

```
Frame object has no attribute 'box'

Window object has no attribute 'box'
```

---

```
self.box=ttk.Combobox(self.frame2 , values[...])
self.button1=tk.Button(self.frame2, command= self.wipe(), text=...)

def wipe(self):
    self.box.get()
```

ALTERNATIVELY i tried:

```
def wipe(self):
    self.frame2.box.get()
```

The goal is to simply get the selected choice from the Combobox.

HERE IS MINIMAL CODING THAT PRODUCES THE SAME ERROR:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class window():
    def __init__(self,root):
        self.frame=tk.Frame(root)
        self.key=tk.Button(self.frame,text='PRESS ME',command=self.wipe())
        self.box=ttk.Combobox(self.frame, options=['1','2','3'])
        self.frame.pack()
        self.key.pack()
        self.box.pack()
    def wipe(self):
        self.box.get()

master=tk.Tk()
master.geometry('400x400')
app=window(master)
master.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please show us a [mcve].

Comment: I added it at the end of my post.

Answer (score 0):

I would add the tag "tkinter" to the question.

**Try the following:**

```
def wipe(self):
    # code

self.box=ttk.Combobox(self.frame2 , values[...])
self.button1=tk.Button(self.frame2, command=wipe, text=...)
```

**Notice the following:**

1. I first defined wipe, only then used it.
2. I am not quite sure why you wanted to do `command=self.wipe()`, as there are two issues here. First, you are setting `command` to the result of `self.wipe()` which is NOT a function. Second, you haven't defined `self.wipe`, you defined `wipe`.
3. `command=wipe` Sets the `command` keyword argument to the
   function `wipe`

Its been long since I dealt with tkinter, if this doesn't work, I'll try to help by checking the docs again.

Comment: Yes i did try defining the function before the widgets but it didn't change anything. I also tried phrasing the command in various other ways which also didn't change much if anything ( i mean the 'command=self.wipe()' , 'self.wipe' etc.)

Comment: Please edit your question to include your attempts.